# IndexOf element in js array using a truth function using underscore or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I need basically the same functionality as Underscore's [find](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#find) but with the index of the element as a result (and not the element itself).

As far as I know, Underscore's [indexOf](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#indexOf) looks for a value and doesn't take a function. Same problem for jQuery's [inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) function.

I came up with the following implementation, but I'm not sure it is the most efficient:

```
function myIndexOf(arr, filter) {
  var index;
  $.each(arr, function (i, elt) { if (filter(elt)) { index=i; return false; } });
  return index;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple implementation:

```
function find(collection, filter) {
    for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
        if(filter(collection[i], i, collection)) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

It will work on *any* indexable object that has a length property, and you can pass a complex filter function of the form `filter(element, index, collection)` (optional parameters).

Answer (score 10):

`_.findIndex` is available in [Lo-Dash](http://lodash.com/docs#findIndex) and [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#findIndex):

```
var characters = [
  { 'name': 'barney',  'age': 36, 'blocked': false },
  { 'name': 'fred',    'age': 40, 'blocked': true },
  { 'name': 'pebbles', 'age': 1,  'blocked': false }
];

_.findIndex(characters, function(chr) {
  return chr.age < 20;
});
// → 2

_.findIndex(characters, { 'age': 36 });
// → 0

_.findIndex(characters, { 'name': 'dino' });
// → -1 (not found)
```

Comment: Underscore also has exactly same method since v1.8.0 (Feb. 19, 2015). http://underscorejs.org/#findIndex

Answer (score 5):

Underscore uses the following implementation:

```
_.find = function(obj, iterator, context) {
    var result;
    _.any(obj, function(value, index, list) {
        if(iterator.call(context, value, index, list)) {
            result = value;
            return true;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

This in turn calls, `_.any`, which calls `_.each`, which calls `Array.prototype.forEach`.  Efficiency isn't exactly the name of the game.  It is more about utility.

If you know for a fact that you are dealing with an array or array-like object, you can use @Thor84no's solution and simply loop through the array until your filter condition is met.  If not, and you may be dealing with objects as well, I would simply rewrite _.find as _.findIndex and use `result = index;`.

Comment: If it is not a matter of efficiency, why _.indexOf and $.inArray are not taking a predicate instead of a value?

Comment: `_.indexOf` targets efficiency and uses either a binary search or the native `Array.prototype.indexOf` function.  This means that they can't use function arguments.  With `_.find`, you're already planning to have a lot of function calls so what's three more?

Answer (score 3):

You can just use a local variable to get that like so:

```
var idx = 0; 
var match = _.detect(my_list, function(itm){
    return itm.something == some_test_value || ++idx == my_list.length && (idx = -1);
}
```

Viola. You got the index AND the matching value. If the iterator reaches the end, the index goes to -1, and if you hit a match, it short-circuits on that index.

Answer (score 2):

It would be more efficient to do the for loop yourself and use `break;` (or `return`) to leave the loop once you've found the index.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (filter(arr[i])) {
        return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think using `for ... in ` to iterate over an array is not a good idea. Please use `for(var i = 0; ... )`. Actually it's even faster, and also works on DOM collections.

Comment: True, I was just in too much of a hurry when writing it. Thanks. On the other hand `for ... in` also works for finding matches in objects (has to be used carefully of course).